# jQuery: Chained Animations Are An Issue, Improving My Code

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout

```
$(".info-graphic-data-box").fadeOut(200);
$(".info-graphic-content").fadeOut(200);
$("#" + currentContentId).parent().fadeIn(500);
$("#" + currentContentId).fadeIn(500);
```

So, in this instance, I have to fade out two elements and then fade in a different two.

The problem here is that the animations are chained ... which means, if you rollover several elements, one after the other, the animations keep going and going and going.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Animations are only chained *if they apply to the same elements*.

To stop any animations that are ongoing before you add new ones, use the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to `stop` the animation right in the middle ... but rather prevent it from continually happening. Almost like jumping to the end of the queue.

Comment: @dcolumbus you're going to need provide your markup, and ideally a jsfiddle that demonstrates the "bad" behaviour.

Comment: @dcolumbus you're not going to 'stop' the animation and leave the element as is, you 'stop' the animation then queue the one to replace it, so it finishes after that.

Answer (score 0):

1- Firstly, create references to your DOM objects:

```
var $idgb = $(".info-graphic-data-box"),
    $igc = $(".info-graphic-content"),
    $cc = $("#" + currentContentId);
```

2- Use callbacks and chaining to ensure proper animation execution:

```
$idgb.fadeOut(200, function(){
    $igc.fadeOut(200, function(){
        $cc.parent().fadeIn(500).end().fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

3- Whenever you think there may be overlap with execution, use the stop() method to cancel any currently running animation:

```
$cc.stop().parent().stop().fadeIn(500, function(){ $cc.fadeIn(500); });
```

The above is pseudo-code... not really sure how you want the animations to truly work on the page (based on user input).

Comment: Caching DOM elements only to use them once does nothing, otherwise I tend to agree.

Comment: Its cleaner and more maintainable. Just a good habit... but, if only EVER and FOREVER used once, absolutely unnecessary as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working for you the way it is, other than the animations not stopping, I'm guessing the issue is'nt the order of the animations, and that all you need is `stop()` :

```
$(".info-graphic-data-box, .info-graphic-content").stop(true, false).fadeOut(200);
$("#" + currentContentId).fadeIn(500).parent().stop(true, false).fadeIn(500);
```

Merged those selectors a little bit aswell.